# Button in table fires both button and table event when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I have a table that displays info on certain components and at the right side of the table, I have a delete button.  As of now, I have it so when clicking on a component's row it brings you to a new page.  Since my delete button is also on that row, it brings me to that page when clicked instead of deleting the component.  Is there a way to make only the button event fire when clicked instead of the table's row event? 
Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
{{#components}}
<tr class="component" data-id={{id}} data-type={{type}}>
        <td>{{general_name}}</td>
        <td>{{type}}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right delete" id="remove" data-id={{id}} data-type={{type}}></button>
        </td>   
    </tr>
{{/components}}
```

And here's the javascript events I have that should route the clicks to the right spot:

```
'click #remove' : 'deleteComponent',
'click .component': 'openComponent',
```

I have tried using jQuery's removeClass("component") on my button but that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using AngularJS here?  `{{id}}`

Comment: I've been using Mustache to throw in values I grab from a database.  I'll add that into my tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop [event propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) when the button is clicked using something like this:

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  //set up your normal button code here...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

stop the event propagation. Place the above line in your deletecomponent (remove event) method.